# Selecting Lat and Long based on circular range

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I am building an application to generate airline dispatches. The user location is queried from the database and they input the minimum distance they want to fly and the maximum distance they want to fly. I need to generate a list of airports that are between this range from their origin airport. I have a function to calculate the distance, but I can only use it if I pull all of my airport data from the database first, which is seriously expensive. Is there a way to do this in the mySQL code.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great Circle Distance is available in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng as a Stored Function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you could do this in the db. I use a similar idea and run the code in a stored procedure - passing in params for lat/lng/radius. The code below should give an idea as to how you could implement this for your own needs I think.

```
begin
    declare strsql varchar(1000);
    declare dbrecords integer default 0;
    declare maxlimit integer default 0;
    declare lat double default 0;
    declare lng double default 0;
    declare radius float default 0;
    declare earth_radius integer default 0;
    declare lon1 float;
    declare lat1 float;
    declare lon2 float;
    declare lat2 float;
    set @lat=param_lat;
    set @lng=param_lng;
    set @radius=cast(param_radius as unsigned);

    set @earth_radius=3956;
    set @lon1 = @lng - @radius/ceil( cos( radians( @lat ) ) * 69 );
    set @lon2 = @lng + @radius/ceil( cos( radians( @lat ) ) * 69 );
    set @lat1 = @lat - ( @radius/69 );
    set @lat2 = @lat + ( @radius/69 );
    set @maxlimit=cast(param_limit as unsigned);

    set @strsql=concat("
    select distinct 
        m.`lat`,
        m.`lng`,
        m.`alt`,
        m.`region`,
        m.`unitaryautharea`,
        c.`council_name`,
        c.`normalised_title`,
        c.`council_lat`,
        c.`council_lng`,
        c.`cipfa_code`,
        c.`snac_id`,
        c.`wdtk_id`,
        c.`wdtk_name`,
        c.`egr_id`,
        c.`os_id`,
        c.`open_data_licence`
        w.`country_name`,

        /* This is the bit that does the main calculations and probably where you want to concentrate - the fields obviously will not relate to your db */

        truncate( @earth_radius * 2 * asin(sqrt( power( sin( (@lat - m.`lat`) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +cos(@lat * pi()/180) * cos(m.`lat` * pi()/180) *power(sin((@lng - m.`lng`) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ) ),3) as 'distance'


        from `metsitelist` m
        left outer join `ukcity_councils` c on c.`normalised_title`=m.`unitaryautharea`
        left outer join `ukcity_districts` d on d.`council_id`=c.`council_id`
        left outer join `ukcouncil_type` t on t.`id`=c.`council_authority_type_id`
        left outer join `ukcounties` ct on ct.`county_id`=c.`county_id`
        left outer join `worldcountries` w on w.`country_id`=c.`country_id`
        left outer join `metregions` r on r.`region`=m.`region`

        /* Here you find records within the range you want */

            where   (
                            ( m.`lat` between @lat1 and @lat2 ) 
                            and 
                            ( m.`lng` between @lon1 and @lon2 )
                    )


            /* ensure records are closer than max radius */ 


            having `distance` <= @radius 
            order by `distance`
            limit 0", @maxlimit ,";");

        prepare stmt from @strsql;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;
end
```

Hope you can make use of the logic here

Comment: My query used a flat world coordinate system :) good work! I'll analyze your calculations, probably they will be useful to my postgrade work. Thanks!

Comment: I can actually understand some of that. Thanks! I will let you know if it solves my problem. Give me a couple of days. I do this stuff on the side :-)

Answer (score 0):

Umm, you can reduce query size, but not compute whole task (easily or not as lightweight as in PHP side) in database. This optimization is not related to PHP, is MySQL (SQL) related only and the target is to reduce drastically number of elements to compute in PHP side.

If you have a maximum distance then you could query about all airports inside that range and use only them to calculate best route.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, name, x, y,
        SQRT(POW(ABS(xpos - x), 2) + POW(ABS(ypos - y), 2)) distance 
        FROM table_name
) temp_table WHERE distance < max_distance
```

It will not resolve the problem, but will help to reduce PHP side work.

Hope it helps.